# How do I get Opera browser to recognize Lightspark?

Tags: flash, opera

I used terminal to install light spark (0.7.2+git20150512-2build4).  When I go to plugins on my browser, Opera, it only shows Chrome PDF viewer.  What do I need to go to get Opera to see that I've installed lightspark?

Comment: What command did you use for installation?

Comment: sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark

Comment: I cant find the opera plugin folder anywhere!!!

Answer (score 1):

The Lightspark plugin only supports the NPAPI (a plugin api). However, Opera (and Chrome) only support the PPAPI on Linux. Therefore, Lightspark won't work.

I recommend that you install the `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package instead. (which isn't open source but I doubt that could be a demand from your side as Opera is a closed source browser)

Comment: Thanks.  Pepperflash works great.  I'm assuming it's safer than adobe flash...  I moved to Opera after firefox did something that I didn't like and never looked back.  Maybe I should check it out again someday. Now to uninstall gnash AND lightspark....  Thanks